# Openresty : proxy server that forwards incoming URLs to another domain If the incoming URL is a valid image URL

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I am using a simple server using openresty, and this is a proxy server that forwards incoming URLs to another domain If the incoming URL is a valid image URL. Currently, we are doing it by checking extensions in lua block. But for some cases, the extension won't be there and the image gives out 403 error code. So is there any way to check the URL response is an image or not in the lua block?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the first bytes of files and check image file signatures.
For example: `jpg, jpeg` - FF D8 FF (FF D8 FF DB, FF D8 FF E0,FF D8 FF E1),
`png` - 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A,
`gif` - 47 49 46 38,
and so on, by searching you can find signature tables of different file types.